# Using Javascript to determine if Web site is public or private

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

So let's assume we have two web sites:

1. one is hosted on a public web hosting account with a public domain name e.g. mydomain.com
2. the other is  hosted on a local computer e.g. my laptop, but is configured to run with the same hostname e.g. mydomain.com, using Apache Virtual Hosts

So both will have the same `window.documentURI` or `window.location.href`.

Is there a way I can determine, using Javascript, which Web site is hosted publicly and which one is hosted privately?!

Thanks

**EDIT**

The reason I need this is I'm finishing up a JQuery Plugin that submits some data to a remote server [analytics basically] and I want to make the feature more secure by preventing spoofing by someone using a local server with the same hostname as the rightful user to mess up the data.

Comment: If your local DNS configuration is such that the local site hijacks the "real" hostname, then it'll be impossible to reach the real site.

Comment: Maybe try the IP address? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thanks. It doesn't quite say how to get the IP address of the local web server, any ideas how I could get this?!

Comment: @HanletEscaño, it will give you the IP of the executing machine not the hosting machine.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I'm not sure I get you. Will it give me `127.0.0.1` for the web site hosted on my local computer?!

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh, 1. it won't, *it will give you the IP of the executing machine not the hosting machine*. 2. You can test it, it is one line code...

Comment: Ok, I just noticed something that could solve the problem, I'll be posting an answer on that shortly.

Comment: I saw your edit, javascript shouldn't be your last line of defense, and in this case I think it shouldn't be even your first line...

Comment: @gdoron Yeah, I figure so, looking at some server-side options while I'm capturing the data. More on that shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can determine, using Javascript, which Web site is hosted publicly and which one is hosted privately?!

**No.** How exactly do you expect it to know?  javascript has a very limited access control to the hosted machine.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could somehow retrieve the IP address from the server and if it's `127.0.0.1` then I'll know it's private. Trying to figure out how I'm going to do that though.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh, I don't think you will get that address but the real IP address of the laptop, you can hardcode that value if you wish using a solution like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/810461/601179). By the way, why do you need it?

Comment: I tried a couple of things on the server-side but can't seem to find a solution. I guess I'm going to have to advise clients to obfuscate their code to provide additional security. I'm keep looking though.

Answer (score 0):

Not without the help of a third party service.

Your javaScript could send two AJAX queries: 1) to return the client's public IP 2) to return the public DNS IP of the domain. You would compare the two results.

Comment: Ok. Is there no way to get the loopback IP address, using javascript, from the local web server?!

Comment: @Chuck Ugwuh - On Windows and Internet Explorer you could use ActiveXObject loading inside of JavaScript (read: JScript) but in the general case, no

Comment: That's way too much hassle for what I'm looking to do. Thanks though.